# horizontal layout when scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a horizontal layout in my page ... whenever user scrolls the page instead of top-to-bottom
layout I want to have left-to-right layout
... with my code on big screens there is empty space after last section and on small screens
last section won't appear.

```js
calcBodyHeight();

function calcBodyHeight() {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
  let height = null;
  sections.forEach(section => {
    height += section.offsetWidth;
  })
  document.body.style.height = `${height}px`;
}
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  const scroll = window.scrollY;
  container.style.left = `-${scroll}px`;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.container {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.container .section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.container .section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: coral;
}

.container .section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container .section:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the initial height is missing from the calculation.

Let's take an example:

```
body.height: 800
body.width: 400
```

After `calcBodyHeight`, `body` height is **1600px** (400 * 4) which means we need to have **1200px** to scroll (the first 400px already presented). But, since `body.height` is **800px** this leaves us with only **800ox** to scroll.

My suggestion is to calculate a bit different

1. Set the `body` height as `section.length * section.height`
2. Get the window ratio (width / height)
3. On scroll, scroll according the ratio

```js
calcBodyHeight();
function calcBodyHeight() {
  const height = [...document.querySelectorAll('.section')]
    .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.offsetHeight, 0);
  document.body.style.height = `${height}px`;
}

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  const scroll = window.scrollY * ratio;
  container.style.left = `-${scroll}px`;
});
```

**Demo**

```js
calcBodyHeight();
function calcBodyHeight() {
  const height = [...document.querySelectorAll('.section')]
    .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.offsetHeight, 0);
  document.body.style.height = `${height}px`;
}

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  const scroll = window.scrollY * ratio;
  container.style.left = `-${scroll}px`;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.container {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.container .section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.container .section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: coral;
}

.container .section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container .section:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure CSS, we can create a container with items within the container. Then rotate the container 90 degrees anti-clockwise and rotate the items 90 degrees clockwise to be the right way up.

```css
.horizontal{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.horizontal > div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">

  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  <div>Item 8</div>
 
</div>
```